# Css style changes when exported to iPad

Tags: css, ios, ipad, html, ios5

I have a page that I'm making, and when I export it, the text goes from being formatted to unformated. I just have the div, with the class, and the text. So, why is it doing it and how can I fix it?

Comment: We cannot even begin to comment on your project without seeing code.

Comment: Need more info as per this : http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551/181292

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mmhh... this could be the problem, when you load the page on mobile internet, not over wlan)
you have to set some params for mobile... you can check, if this works for you

this solved my problem:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta content="minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
```